# Why is my PDF showing only zeroes when generated using pdfkit and jinja2 in Python?

Tags: python, jinja2, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I generated PDF in python using pdfkit from html file, but the pdf generated shows only zeroes (0).
Below is the code.

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import pdfkit

template_loader = FileSystemLoader('.')
temp_env = Environment(loader=template_loader)

template = temp_env.get_template("sample-template.html")
output = template.render(curse = "CSE")

with open('result.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)

wkpath = "C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=wkpath)
pdfkit.from_file('result.html', 'output' + '.pdf',  options={"enable-local-file-access": ""},
                 configuration=config)
```

[Output PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Whql.png)

wkhtmltopdf is installed.

Comment: Those aren't zeroes, they're placeholders for non-printing characters. This is usually a character encoding problem.

Comment: @KJ how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the font which the HTML template is using, the font may not work when converting to the PDF.
I changed the font-family in the CSS from 'FontAwesome' to 'Times New Roman' and it works.